# How to accurate statistics how fast dart code runs

Tags: flutter, dart

I write a test method, try to statistics code running speed, below is my test code:

```
test('speed',  (){
    int count = 10000;

    int t1 = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    }
    print("first for loop spend ${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - t1}");

    int t2 = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {

    }
    print("second for loop spend ${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - t2}");
});
```

I run this test method, and the console print:

> first for loop spend 106
>
> second for loop spend 440

I can`t understand why the second for loop cost more time than the first loop, they do the same thing.

And what is the best way to accurate statistics how fast dart code runs.

Dart SDK Version 2.5.2
Run on MacOS 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using something like [Stopwatch](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) to measure elapsed time.

```
test('speed',  (){
    int count = 10000;

    final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    print("first for loop spend ${stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds}");

    final stopwatch1 = Stopwatch()..start();
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {

    }
    stopwatch1.stop();
    print("second for loop spend ${stopwatch1.elapsedMilliseconds}");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have tried to use Stopwatch but get the same result.